# What is wrong with this regular expression?

Tags: preg-match

I'm trying to learn some basic regular expression and having a hard time getting it to work.

What is wrong with this?

```
if (preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}", $url)) {
```

It must be something to do with my technique since I can hardly get any examples to work.

Comment: Isn't `{1,}` the same as `+`?  Or doesn't PHP reg exs do `+`?

Comment: Tips for asking good questions: 1/ Include the code (done). 2/ Detail expected behaviour (not done). 3/ Detail actual behaviour (not done). Hmm. that's only 33%, hardly a 'pass' mark :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo In terms of average SO questions, YsoL8's question is quite far on the 'good' side. It is in readable english and, although a bit vague (i.e. what exactly is 'wrong', what happened when he tried to get the examples to 'work'), it is still in my opinion an answerable question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the slashes. @paxdiablo, Stephen sorry for the vagueness - I assumed the mistake would be easy to spot for a non-novice.

Comment: The missing "/" mistake was easy to spot - it was just more if you were having 'program isn't working at all' problems, or just 'regexp isn't catching what I want to catch/is catching too much' problems! I assumed it was the former since without a "/" on either side the code shouldn't even run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP regular expressions have a forward slash (/) on either side of them. What you want is:

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}/", $url)
```

I assume you realise that this just matches any alphanumeric string, right? As an aside, I find websites like [this](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php) useful for testing PHP regexps.